# Proof that rank equals number of independent rows

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, matrix-rank

Suppose I know the rank $r$ of a matrix $A$ by reducing it to echelon form $U$ ( Rank is defined as the number of pivots).

Since the row space of $U$ and $A$ is the same, and that the dimension of row space of $U$ is $r$, I therefore know that row space of $A$ has dimension $r$ as well  .
Therefore Any basis for the row space of A will have $r$ vectors in it because the number of vectors in a basis is independent of the basis itself.

Now can I use this knowledge to find the number of linearly independent rows of $A$?

**Attempt**:

The independent rows of A will form a basis for it's row space. But every basis should have $r$ vectors, therefore there are $r$ independent rows in $A$.

Hence the rank = number of independent rows.

Is the attempt correct.

Comment: What is your definition of rank? One of them is exactly the number of independent rows. Another one is the number of independent columns. Another one (the best one if you ask me) is the dimension of the range. Yet another one is the greatest order of a non-zero minor. What is the one you are using?

Comment: I'm going through Dr Strangs book. It starts by defining rank to be the number of pivots.